# Compute $\det A$ for the following elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$ A = P_2^4 = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 &  0
\end{bmatrix} $

$ A = Q_2^4(-4) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -4\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &  1
\end{bmatrix} $

$ A = S_2(-2) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix} $

I know it's a stupid question but I started learning matrices and I can't find $ S , Q $ and $P$ in theory can you tell me what that means?

Comment: P refers to a permutation matrix. More specifically the P matrix here refers to the permutation of $(1,2,3,4)$ to $(1,4,3,2)$. The numbers are just placeholders, basically the fourth and second objects switch places.

Comment: Do I change the second and fourth places ?

Comment: Yes, that is what the matrix does, essentially. If you multiply any vector with the first matrix, you'll see that the second and fourth components of that vector will be switched.

Comment: These notations are non-standard. I think they are the authors' own notations. $P_i^j$ is the matrix that switches row $i$ and row $j$ of a matrix or vector. $Q_i^j(k)$ is the shear matrix that adds $k$ times the $j$-th row of a matrix/vector to the $i$-th row. $S_i(k)$ is the scaling matrix that multiplies the $i$-th row of a matrix/vector by the factor $k$. It is implicitly assumed that $i\ne j$ in the notations $P_i^j$ and $Q_i^j(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We proceed by using the hints given by @twosigma.

$\det{P_2^4} = -1$ because $P_2^4$ is obtained by swapping the second and forth rows of the identity matrix.

$\det{Q_2^4} = 1$ because $Q_2^4$ is obtained by from the identity by adding a multiple $-4$ of the forth row to the second row.

$\det{S_2} = -2$ because $S_2$ is obtained by multiplying $-2$ to one row of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. The identity matrix has determinant $1$.
2. Exchanging two rows of a matrix multiplies the determinant by $-1$.
3. Adding a multiple of one row to another does not change the determinant.
4. Multiplying a row by a non-zero number multiplies the determinant by that number.